# Pequeño error de tipeo al finalizar encuesta de desarrolladores

Tags: bug, estado-completado, encuesta-para-desarrolladores

Acabe de realizar la encuesta para desarrolladores. Al finalizar la misma se muestra un agradecimiento y en esta vista existen dos errores de escritura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En lugar de

> Muchas gracias por completar la encuesta para desarrolladores de **2018de** Stack Overflow. Ganarás la medalla de **Censoen** Stack Overflow en español.

Debería ser:

> Muchas gracias por completar la encuesta para desarrolladores de **2018 de** Stack Overflow. Ganarás la medalla de **Censo en** Stack Overflow en español.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto se ha corregido pero tardará unas horas para actualizarse en el sistema.

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: 04:56 pm en Bogotá, Colombia y el error sigue.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave actualize la respuesta para agregar un screenshot donde se ve que al fin se ha corregido :)